# Find \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2n+1}

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please explain how this infinite sequence gets into an $e$ form?

$$a_n = \sqrt[n]{2n+1}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{2n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{\ln(2n+1)^{1/ n}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} e^\frac{\ln(2n+1)}{n}.$$

How does the nth root of something become $e$ to the natural log?

Comment: since exponents and logs are inverse operations and both correspond to continous functions on the relevant domains, so if $\lim \frac{\log(2n+1)}{n}$ exist, surely does $\mathrm{exp}\lim \frac{\log(2n+1)}{n}=\lim\mathrm{exp} \frac{\log(2n+1)}{n}=\lim(2n+1)^{1/n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember the definition and basic properties of logarithms:

$$\text{def.}:\;\;\log_ax=y\iff a^y=x\;,\;\;\log a^n=n\log a$$

and since $\;e^x\,,\,\,\log x\;$ are functions inverse to each other, we get

$$e^{n\log a}=e^{\log a^n}=a^n\implies\sqrt[n] a=a^{1/n}=e^{\frac1n\log a}=e^{\log a^{1/n}}$$

BTW, your limit is way easier, imo, with the squeeze theorem:

$$1\le\sqrt[n]{2n+1}\le\sqrt[n]{2n+2n}=\sqrt[n]4\sqrt[n]n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot1=1$$

Comment: I agree 100%, I would have never done it this way. But I was try to understand how this is possible, but I have it now..  Thanks

Comment: Actually don't you mean $\sqrt[n]{2n+2}$

Comment: @RobertKellogg No...but it really doesn't matter, does it? One gets the same result this or that way... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because $e^{\ln x}=x$. If you take the logarithm of both sides, then
$$
\begin{align}
\ln(e^{\ln x})&=\ln x\\
\ln x&=\ln x.
\end{align}
$$
In your question, $x=\sqrt[n]{2n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I guess where I am confused, couldn't you just assume the limit will be $1$ because the $lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n} = 1$ Why go to the trouble of showing it as an exponent?

Comment: @RobertKellogg Yes, but you'd have to calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1$ first, so why not just do it directly?

Answer (score 0):

$$x^n = \exp(\ln(x^n)),$$

because $y = \exp(\ln(y))$. 
Indeed, the exponential function is the inverse the Napierian logarithm function ln.

$$ \forall x \geq 0, \ y = \exp(x) \Longleftrightarrow \ln(y) = x.$$